# filtering array with firebase and vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

i´m doing a webapp with vuejs and firebase. I got stack using filter an array for 'push' into a data table.

i think i follow correctly de instructions of how to use the filter() method, but is not working

```
methods: {

 consulProds {
  let resultado = await db.collection('productos')
           .get()                

  resultado.docs.forEach(doc => {
          let productosTot = doc.data()

          let productosInd= productosTot.filter(producto=> 
                            producto.precio== 99)

           this.productosind.push(productosInd)    

  })
 }
}
```

when i do the 'push' without the line code of 'filter' method and using 'doc.data()', it works and i get the array in my 'data table'. But does not happend anything using the 'filter'.

Comment: probably because there is no `doc.data().precio` that equals 99?

Comment: yes there is. when i do: '  this.productosind.push(doc.data()) ', whith out the line code that is using 'filter', the data came out ok.

Comment: can you add some of `doc.data()` so we can help you further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is most probably because `productosTot` is not an Array but "just" a JavaScript Object (that is not an Array), see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.html#data

Just check the value of `precio` with an `if`, as follows:

```
methods: {

 consulProds {
  let resultado = await db.collection('productos').get()                

  resultado.docs.forEach(doc => {
     let producto = doc.data()
     if (producto.precio == 99) this.productosind.push(producto)    
  })
 }

}
```